# setTimeout multiple times

Tags: jquery, css

I am using setTimeout to animate an svg logo when a page loads. There are 3 steps in the animation:

Step 1: fadeIn the logo when the page loads.

Step 2: animate the logo icon 1 second later (using CSS translate to move the icon).

Step 3: fadeIn a period/dot on the logo 1 second later.

This all works fine, but it feels like there should be a more efficient way and I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Here's my code:

```
$(window).ready(function(){
  // fadein logo as page loads (CSS opacity).
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $('.logo').css('opacity', '1') 
  },1000);

  // move logo icon 1 second later (CSS translateX).
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $('.move').addClass('active') 
  }, 2000);

  // fadein period 1 second later (CSS opacity).
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $('.period').css('opacity', '1') 
  }, 3000);
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Couldn't you just use keyframe animations? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Comment: > `there should be a more efficient way` - single three-step css animation.

Comment: I think you're right about keyframes. I'll try it this way and see what I can come up with. Thanks

Comment: There are mainly 3 ways to do it: CSS keyframes, SMIL and Javascript animation engines (ie. $.animate(), [velocity.js](http://velocityjs.org/)). Of the three, the last ones are the most flexible. [A 4th](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) is being developed, but with poor browser support so far. Goals of WA_API are to *"define a model for synchronization and timing of changes"* and to *"define an application programming interface for interacting with this model"*. In current form your question is off-topic as too broad. Please update it with your research.

Comment: You ask: what is *"the most efficient"*. What does that mean? Do you want the *best looking* (smooth, exact) animation or the lightest one (in terms of resources used)? To make it short, for your case, given its simplicity, what you have is just right - you don''t need more. If you needed [runtime controls](https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/#article-header-id-5), you would probably want to have a look at [gsap](https://greensock.com/gsap).

Comment: By efficient I meant 'least amount of repetitive code', but as suggested, I scrapped the JS and replaced it with keyframe animation, and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to nest them like this.

```
$(window).ready(function({ 
  setTimeout(function() { 
    $('.logo').css('opacity', '1');

    setTimeout(function() { 
      $('.move').addClass('active') ;

      setTimeout(function() { 
        $('.period').css('opacity', '1') ;
      }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  },1000); 
});
```

Note: I'm on my phone, so I couldn't test it.

Comment: Basically when timeout ends it runs that code and there is another timeout, so it should work.

Comment: Well, I think efficiency is good enough. But if you mean code shortening than I don't know any better.

Comment: But definitely try keyframes as guys said in the comments.